# Is a question of form "What are some good universities to do a PhD in topic X?" legitimate to be asked in the site?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, one ask what are some of the good institutes in some particular speciality that have a good staff in a particular branch of science. Is this site a good place to ask such questions? If not, where is the appropriate place and how can one get some information about this?

Comment: Welcome to AC.SE. As you may know, voting on meta is a little different than on the main site. On meta a down vote on a question generally means No and an upvote means Yes. So in this case, despite your question being a great question for meta, I have given it a down vote.

Comment: Your undergraduate advisor or other mentors are one place to look for answers. Any answer given here may well become invalid next year if key staff move somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

No, as per the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this would be considered a "shopping question" and would be closed with the reason:

> "Shopping" questions, which seek recommendations or lists of individual universities, academic programs, publishers, journals, research topics or similar as an answer or seek an assessment or comparison of such, are off-topic here.

There is also more information about shopping questions on the main meta site. See for example [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)